# Grouping by DATE in SQL returning nil

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, date

I'm struggling to understand why grouping by DATE on a datetime column in SQLite in Rails is returning nil. I want to return a count of users that have a value in the startdate field, grouped by date.

Can anyone help? Removing the DATE aspect of the below query returns the results as I would expect. See the different queries and results below:

`User.where("startdate IS NOT NULL").group("DATE(startdate)").count`

Gives

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, DATE(startdate) AS date_startdate 
FROM "users" 
WHERE (startdate IS NOT NULL) 
GROUP BY DATE(startdate)
```

=> `{nil=>10}`

What I would expect is an array of dates (e.g. {"2013-06-04"=>3, "2013-06-10"=>4,
"2013-06-11"=>3}. In the query below which doesn't have the DATE operator, the results are more as I would expect, but obviously I don't want to group by time too (in my actual DB there are different times on the same dates).

```
User.where("startdate IS NOT NULL").group("(startdate)").count
```

Gives

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, (startdate) AS startdate 
FROM "users" 
WHERE (startdate IS NOT NULL) 
GROUP BY (startdate)
```

=> `{"2013-06-04 17:27:30.553802+0000"=>3, "2013-06-10 09:24:06.207327+0000"=>4,
"2013-06-11 12:20:37.745819+0000"=>3}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest [date formated string](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) SQLite expects for your data is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS`.

If all your dates are in same timezone, `+0000`, you may ignore `DATE` function at all and compare substring:

```
User.where("startdate IS NOT NULL").group("SUBSTR(startdate,1,10)").count
```

Anyway, SQLite doesn't perform date comparisons. In fact, `DATE` function always returns `TEXT`.

If you deal with different timezones (better try to deal with them in your application), additional computation may be done using [Date/time functions modifiers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

EDIT:

As [@chuck.p.lee correctly corrected me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615898/grouping-by-date-in-sql-returning-nil/19617172?noredirect=1#comment29145840_19617172), closest format is now `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS+HH:MM`. So, converting your dates to this is pretty easy using some string manipulation (truncating sub-milisecond part):

```
SUBSTR(startdate, 1, 23) || SUBSTR(startdate, 27, 3) || ':' || SUBSTR(startdate, 30,2)
```

Now your query may be correctly written as:

```
User.where("startdate IS NOT NULL").group("DATE(SUBSTR(startdate, 1, 23) || SUBSTR(startdate, 27, 3) || ':' || SUBSTR(startdate, 30,2))").count
```

Comment: Brilliant - the first query did the job as they are all in the same timezone - thank you. FYI, the second threw an error `syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting $end` - perhaps it needs correcting for the community? Anyway, thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

[date()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function expects time zone to match format "[-+]HH:MM" or "Z":

```
2013-10-07 08:23:19.120
2013-10-07T08:23:19.120Z
2013-10-07 08:23:19.120-04:00
```

Comment: "Formats 2 through 10 may be optionally followed by a timezone indicator of the form "[+-]HH:MM" or just "Z"."

Answer (score 1):

Convert date to string of the format mm/dd/yyyy and then group by that string

this is how ms sql server code would look like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, convert(varchar(10),startdate, 101) AS date_startdate FROM      "users" WHERE (startdate IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY date_startdate
```

Comment: But this is SQLite, and `mm/dd/yyyy` is worst idea ever for coding dates!

Answer (score -1):

Your sql query is correct and RoR command as well.

It works fine on Postgresql. I think the problem is using DATE function on sqlite. May be its case-sensitive and you should try "date" function instead "DATE" but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: SQLite is not case sensitive.